# Have an icon next to page title using html / ejs

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I am trying to put an icon next to my page title. I have read quite a few articles and similar questions on the internet but i still can't see my little icon up there next to the page title. I literally don't know what is wrong with my code.

I have the following directories among other: data/public, data/files, public (which includes all my css files), views (which includes all my ejs files). Inside the /views folder i have a few folders and a few files that are responsible for my viewing experience while using the web app i am building. Now in the /views/includes directory i have a file named head.ejs which contains all my head code i will use in pretty much every other ejs file. so i just have the head.ejs file and i can include it in every ejs file i want. The head.ejs file looks like that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/data/public/boxTitle.jpg" type="image/jpg" /> -->
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title><%= pageTitle %></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

I expected to see the icon up there but still haven't seen it. I have tried to move my favicon.ico image around in different directories and play a bit around with the paths. the best for me is for the image to be in the /data/public/ directory. while the head.ejs is in the /views/includes/ directory. The image is 16x16, black and white. Tried with a jpg image, too. I am probably failing really hard cause it's seems pretty easy and straight forward but... Any help is appreciated! I will delete the post if the answer is totally obvious and the post is worthless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your icon is in your `public` folder inside an `images` folder.
If you have defined your public folder as you mentioned, with something like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

then you can easily display your icon this way:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/images/your-icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```